# Animation not working on android activity

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, animation

I am trying to animate view when the activity starts but it doesn't work.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/dark_blue"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bull Rent"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="Tagline"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**top_animation.xml (Under anim directory)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:duration="850"
android:startOffset="100">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100"
    android:fromYDelta="0"/>

<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val binding by viewBinding(ActivityMainBinding::inflate)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    //hide the status bar
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val topAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.top_animation)
    binding.textView.startAnimation(topAnimation)
    binding.textView2.startAnimation(topAnimation)

 }

}
```

Its not showing the animation both on real device and on emulator...dont know where the problem is coming from.
I have looked at it critically but cant figure out, also searched but cant seem to see where my error is coming from. Is there a library or do we need to enable animation somewhere in android studio.

Other apps animation works well on my phone. So its not a device problem.

Answer (score 0):

For some weird reasons (Not known to me). This is caused when accessing the views via **viewBinding**. The animation just wont work.

When I switched to accessing views via **findViewById**, It worked!

So access your views via `findViewById` and it would work.